# position div near other div's

Tags: css, html

i can't position div like i want. i searched all around internet and i can't find the solution.
 [image: My work]

1. I want div (dark grey color) position within red square. and my
2. My other target to auto size div (the same one) to fit red square.

Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/x46Lp/):

```
<body>
    <div id="functions"></div>
    <div id="sidemeniu"></div>
    <div id="servers">hi...</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Check out the demo is this that you want](http://jsfiddle.net/aSyGn/1/)
Encapsulated it Inside a Div

### Html

```
<body>
    <div id="functions"></div>
    <div>
        <div id="sidemeniu"></div>
    <div id="servers">hi...</div>
    </div>    

</body>
```

### Css

```
#functions {
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 155px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: black;
}
#sidemeniu {
    width: 20%;
    height: 300px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 7px;
    padding-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: darkgray;
    float:left;
}
#servers {
    background-color: grey;

        float:right;
     width:78%; // changed width here to accomadate  inside the div
    height: 300px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define the div of the dark grey within the div of the red one; ex:-

```
<div id="red">
<div id="grey">hi..
</div>
</div>
```

Also in the div of dark grey add the foll properties:-

```
{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
position:absolute;// NOt
left:0px;// Required
top:0px;// Though
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```